# validation before attribute setters can type cast

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an object with an attribute called value which is of type big decimal. In the class definition i have validates_numericality_of.

However if i:

```
a.value = 'fire'
```

'fire' ends up getting typecast to the correct type before the validation fires so:

```
a.valid? => true
```

How do get the validation to fire before the typecast?

Thanks

Dan

Answer (score 16):

From [ActiveRecord::Base docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html):

> Sometimes you want to be able to read
>   the raw attribute data without having
>   the column-determined typecast run its
>   course first. That can be done by
>   using the `<attribute>_before_type_cast`
>   accessors that all attributes have.
>   For example, if your `Account` model has
>   a balance attribute, you can call
>   `account.balance_before_type_cast` or
>   `account.id_before_type_cast`.
>
> This is especially useful in
>   validation situations where the user
>   might supply a string for an integer
>   field and you want to display the
>   original string back in an error
>   message. Accessing the attribute
>   normally would typecast the string to
>   0, which isn’t what you want.

Comment: Fyi, if you want to do this without getting weird validation messages in your views. E.g. "<attribute> before type cast must be a number" you can create a [custom validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-validators) that checks `"#{attribute}_before_type_cast"` instead of just checking the attribute itself.

Comment: @Ajedi32 Or pass :message option to validator?

Comment: @sheerun No, that won't work because the message option doesn't change what attribute the validation error is associated with. (E.g. In "<attribute> before type cast must be a number", you could only use that option to change the "must be a number" part of the message.)

Answer (score 1):

A new gem has been created to help [validate types in rails](https://github.com/yez/validates_type).

An [explanatory blog post](http://jakeyesbeck.com/2015/05/10/validates-type/) exists to answer more of the "why" it was created in the first place.

With this library your code could be:

```
class SomeObject < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_type :value, :big_decimal
end
```

This will throw an exception when anything except a float is assigned to `value` instead of quietly casting the `value` to a BigDecimal and saving it.