# Rails: Regex not working in number format validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

In a Rails 5 validation, I'm trying to ensure that an inputted float have at most 3 digits after the decimal. Partly following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173530/ruby-on-rails-validate-a-cost) I have

`validates :modifier, presence: true, format: { with: /\A\d+(?:\.\d{0,3})?\z/ }, numericality: { less_than: 100_000}`

But the following test fails (using the [shoulda matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) gem):

`should_not allow_value(12345.1234).for(:modifier)`

Error message: `Expected errors when modifier is set to 12345.1234, got no errors`

Even though the following tests succeed:

`should allow_value(12345.123).for(:modifier)
should allow_value(12345).for(:modifier)
should_not allow_value(123456).for(:modifier)`

Probably it has something to do with the regex only working for a string, whereas the `:modifier` attribute I'm working with is coming in as a float. So I need to find a way to run the validation on a stringified version of the float...

Comment: Check out Rubular for testing Regex! 
http://rubular.com/

Comment: The regex I've provided works as expected on Rubular.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that Rails was doing automatic [typecasting](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-rails-works-type-casting) given that my database had set the column as `decimal, precision: 5, scale: 3`.

In order to validate the input properly, I needed to run this validation:

`validates :modifier_before_type_cast, presence: true, format: { with: /\A\d+(?:\.\d{0,3})?\z/ }, numericality: { less_than: 100_000 }`

My most relevant help ended up coming from here: [validation before attribute setters can type cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766582/validation-before-attribute-setters-can-type-cast)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
validates :modifier, presence: true, format: { with: /\A\d+(\.\d{0,3})?$/ }, numericality: { less_than: 100_000}
```

Comment: The failing test still fails, and also the 123456 test fails. And here's an important error message (I'm using Rails 5):

```ArgumentError: The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $), which may present a security risk. Did you mean to use \A and \z, or forgot to add the :multiline => true option?```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, taking a look!

Comment: @JayQuigley try what I've updated it to.  The 123456 test is passing when I test it, so let me know if it isn't for you

Answer (score 0):

It seems like regex in your `validates` doesn't work.

This expression works

```
/\A\d+(?:\.?\d{0,3})\z/
```

in model

```
validates :modifier, presence: true, format: { with: /\A\d+(?:\.?\d{0,3})\z/ }, numericality: { less_than: 100_000}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

This one works for many countries and you can write it with or without spaces (`\s*`):

```
validates :bank_account, allow_blank: true, uniqueness: true, format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s*[0-9]{4}\s*([a-zA-Z0-9]?){0,12}\s*[0-9]{4}\z/}
```

This is a non-exhaustive list of countries it works for: Belgium, Croatia, France, Germany, Luxembourg, Netherlands, Poland, Romania, Spain. I checked it online with this useful tool https://regexr.com/

One of the countries it doesn't work for is Bulgaria for example.